# Drawing World Map - Performance & Interaction - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, core-graphics

I’d like to use a Shapefile to generate an interactive world map.  I was able to import the data and use CG Paths to draw the map into one large view.

The map needs to support panning, zooming and touch interaction.  For that, I've created a UIScrollView and placed the MapView (large view with all of the countries drawn) into it.

I need to improve two aspects of it:

### Performance / rendering

I have drawn the map much larger than the screen size, in order to make it look reasonable when I zoom in.  There are a few problems with this.  First, when I'm zoomed out, I need the border stroke/line to be wider so they are visible.  When I zoom in, I'd like the stroke to be a thinner.  Also, when I zoom in, I can still see that the map is a blurry.  I don't want to increase the view size too much.

How can I make the map look crisp when I'm zoomed in?  I attempted to redraw the map on zoom in, but it takes far too long.  Can I somehow only re render onscreen stuff?

### Touch Interaction

I need to be able to have a touch event for every different country.

### Possible approach?

I was thinking of trying to separate every country onto it’s own view.  That should make touches easy to handle.  Then I’m thinking I can possibly redraw the appropriate views that are on screen/zoomed to.

I've played with an app that does something similar ("World Maps"), and I can see that when you pan or zoom, the map is blurry for a second but then becomes clear.  What is going on there?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work (I've never tries it and haven't looked closely at the API) but I think that maybe you could use a map view and the custom tiles API (possibly using NSURLProtocol) to render tiles for different zoom levels on demand.

Comment: Well, I was sort of going in the direction of not using MapKit, because I don't actually want to display a real map.  Just a graphical representation.

Comment: have you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

use mapkit and provide custom tiles. dont reinvent the wheel and try to write yet another map framework

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to create different scaled area image from the big map image. how to say... imagine the google map, how it works... I think that provide many different zoom factor image for every area of the world... then merged display on the screen while user need show it ...

use code implemented the map effect is impossible on current iPhone device, out of the ability of the iOS device